# Flash Player embedded in QWebView causes breakpoint in Xcode

Tags: xcode, qt, gdb, flash

I've a got Qt QWebView that just contains a SWF running in the embedded flash player.

i.e. the HTML looks like this:

```
<body style="margin: 0px; overflow:hidden; background: #FFFFFF">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="preview.swf" width="100%" height="100%">             
    </object>
</body>
```

Everything is working in my app, but when the QWebView is first loaded a break point is always triggered in Xcode's debugger.  The call stack looks like this:

```
#0  0x9642d126 in Debugger
#1  0x77a03785 in dyld_stub_write
#2  0x77a03a3f in NP_Initialize
#3  0x2663fcfd in WebCore::PluginPackage::load
#4  0x2664041f in WebCore::PluginPackage::fetchInfo
#5  0x264dffa7 in WebCore::PluginPackage::createPackage
#6  0x264daf55 in WebCore::PluginDatabase::refresh
#7  0x264db31c in WebCore::PluginDatabase::installedPlugins
#8  0x2661d519 in WebCore::FrameLoaderClientQt::objectContentType
#9  0x26361e26 in WebCore::HTMLPlugInImageElement::isImageType
```

and the console is displaying:

```
Debugger() was called!
```

So pretty clearly dyld_stub_write is calling Debugger() and breaking (on purpose presumably) ... any idea why this might be happening?  How can I make it go away?  It's very annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The release build of Adobe's Flash/SWF plug-in has been compiled with at least one call to `Debugger()`. Yes, this is lame. Yes, it's Adobe's fault.

To work around it you need to tell Xcode not to break on the `Debugger()` call. You can do this per-executable by right-clicking the executable in the Groups and Files list, selecting **Get Info** and unchecking **Break on Debugger()/DebugStr()** in the Debugging tab. You can also disable it in the **Run** menu, as zneak pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see to make it go away is to stop breaking on Debugger(). Uncheck it in Xcode's Run menu.

If you depend on calls to Debugger() in your own project, I suggest you use "regular" breakpoints.